# Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that, $\forall\varepsilon >0$, there exist rationals $q$ and $q'$ such that $q<x<q'$ and $|q-q'|<\varepsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am new to analysis and I have trouble doing this proof. I know it has to do with the Density Theorem but I am not able to do it. Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: The *constructive* way: $$q=\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor-1}{n}\quad q'=\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor+1}{n}\quad n>\frac2{\epsilon}$$

Comment: Can you show that there is a rational in the interval $\left(x-\frac{\epsilon}2,x\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since the rational numbers are dense in the reals, there are a rational number $q\in(x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ and $q'\in(x,x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Try to prove that you can pick up $q, q^\prime $ written as $\frac{m} {2^n}$ where $m, n$ are integers.